# Python replace innermost 2 bracket characters in a string

Tags: python

I am trying to replace `[[` with `{{` and `]]` with `}}` in a file. 
However I only want this to work on the innermost 2 brackets if there are more than 2 consecutive square brackets. 
So if I have this: `[[[[` it should be replaced with `[[{{`, and `]]]]` should be replaced with `}}]]`

Comment: OK! What have have you tried, and what's the problem with it? I would recommend a regex with negative lookarounds.

Comment: I haven't used regex before, so far the script just uses String.replace("[[", "{{"). But this doesn't work properly for more than 2 consecutive characters

Comment: Yes, that won't work. Start looking into regular expressions (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and see e.g. https://regex101.com/r/wU2yF9/2. However, SO, is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: What if the inner bracket and the outer ones aren't consecutive?  In the string `[[123[[456]]789]]` do all the brackets get replaced?

Comment: That isn't a problem, they will all be replaced

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative look-ahead (to find the innermost left brackets) and negative look-behind (to find the innermost right brackets):

```
>>> import re
>>> original = "[This] [[is]] [[[a]]] [[[[test]]]]"
>>> left_replaced = re.sub("\[\[(?!\[)", "{{", original)
>>> left_replaced
'[This] {{is]] [{{a]]] [[{{test]]]]'
>>> result = re.sub("(?<!\])\]\]", "}}", left_replaced)
>>> result
'[This] {{is}} [{{a}}] [[{{test}}]]'
```

Note that this will replace four square brackets in a row if the two pairs are separated by a space or any other character (it was unclear from your question how you wanted to handle this situation):

```
>>> original = "[This] [[is]] [[[a]]] [[ [[test]] ]]"
>>> left_replaced = re.sub("\[\[(?!\[)","{{",original)
>>> left_replaced
'[This] {{is]] [{{a]]] {{ {{test]] ]]'
>>> result = re.sub("(?<!\])\]\]", "}}", left_replaced)
>>> result
'[This] {{is}} [{{a}}] {{ {{test}} }}'
```

Comment: You could avoid the space-separated case with `\s*`, if desirable.

Comment: Yes, and the `\s*` would go inside the negative look-ahead/behind for each case: `\[\[(?!\s*\[)` and `(?<!\]\s*)\]\]`

Comment: I didn't see the requirement that there had to be more than two consecutive in order to replace, so I updated my answer to handle this.

Comment: it's innermost two if more than two, I think if *only* two they *should* be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

While regexes are the best way to do this if efficiency is a major consideration, if you only have a few thousand strings of moderate length, you can do this with code that is much more legible:

```
string = '[[abc[[cde]]ghi]]]]'
leftBrackets = [i for i in range(len(string)-1) if string[i:i+2] == '[[' and 
     (i == len(string)-2 or string[i+2] != '[')]
rightBrackets = [i for i in range(len(string)-1) if string[i:i+2] == ']]' and 
     (i == len(string)-2 or string[i+2] != ']')]
for index in leftBrackets:
    string = string[:index] + '{{' + string[index+2:]
for index in rightBrackets:
    string = string[:index] + '}}' + string[index+2:]
print(string)
```

This prints

```
{{abc{{cde}}ghi]]}}
```

Regular expressions are great if you're expert at using them, but I'm not.  I've gone through "Mastering Regular Expressions", but I don't have much occasion for using them, so I've forgotten all but the most basic things.  While I can look up the advanced stuff, I can't remember it, so after a week or so, my code becomes incomprehensible to me.  Therefore, I would not even consider using regular expressions for something like this unless straightforward code like the above turned out to be too slow.

Others will disagree with me, of course, and leave rude comments, but you might want to consider my view of the matter.

BTW, in practice, I would put the definitions of leftBrackets and rightBrackets in `try except` blocks and eliminate the check for the end of the range.

Comment: I think spending the time to better understand regular expressions would be a lot better than the code you have above. That code will be much less efficient, and is much more verbose. `re.sub("(?<!\])\]\]", "}}", re.sub("\[\[(?!\[)", "{{", s))` is all you need to do this with regexs. The only "advanced stuff" in there is the fact that you have to be careful escaping the brackets and negative lookaround, which really isn't that complicated. I am not trying to bash your answer, I just don't think this is the best advice.

Comment: Also, the desired result is `{{abc{{cde}}ghi}}]]`, not `{{abc{{cde}}ghi]]}}`

Comment: @Jake Griffith I understand what you're saying, but I just don't agree.  Regexes are good if you do a lot of text processing, but if you don't, they're not very valuable.  I find that whenever I decide to use regexes (once in a blue moon) I have to spend a lot of time re-learning them.  I guess a misread the specs when I wrote this, but I wouldn't have any trouble fixing it, because I can read what it's doing.  Yes. it's verbose, inelegant, and inefficient, but if I just have to convert a file to another format, who cares?

Answer (score -1):

using regex, you can use lookaheads and lookbehinds:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "[[{{ }}]] [[ ]]"
>>> s = "[[[[ ]]]] [[ ]]"
>>> a = re.sub("(?<=\[{2})\[\[","{{",s)
>>> a
'[[{{ ]]]] [[ ]]'
>>> a = re.sub("(?=\]{4})\]\]","}}",s)
>>> a
'[[[[ }}]] [[ ]]'
```

Comment: Using positive lookarounds makes this very inflexible - why not *negative* lookarounds?

Answer (score -2):

There may be a better regex than mine, but here is a quick solution.

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(.*)\[{3}(.*?)\]{3}(.*)')
test_str = u"[[[[ text ]]]]"
matches = re.match(p, test_str)
if matches:
    print matches.group(1) + '[{{' + matches.group(2) + '}}]' + matches.group(3)
    # [[{{ text }}]]
```

Comment: I just asked the OP about this a moment ago.  He would want all the brackets replaced, as I understand it his answer to my comment.

Comment: I see. Updated answer.

Comment: Now this won't work for `"[[text]]"` (`"{{text}}"`), and it still won't work for `"[[first]] [[second]]"` (`"{{first}} {{second}}"`) or `"[[one [[two]] three]]"` (`"{{one {{two}} three}}"`)

Comment: @Jake - OP says he/she "only wants this to work on the innermost 2 brackets **if there are more than 2 consecutive square brackets**". And no sample data was given, so I assumed there was only a single element.

Comment: It's innermost two *if more than two*. It's both if there are not more than two (see comments on OPs question). But, this still won't work for `"[[[first]]] [[[second]]]"` or `"[[[one [[[two]]] three]]]"`. It will only replace one set per string.

Comment: How about we just agree the question needs more clarification than argue in the comments, eh?